# Issue with Flyway database migration when running same applications running at the same time

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

Here is my app workflow. I have one springboot app running in either jetty/tomcat. The app is integrated with flyway database migration features with MySql/MariaDB.

The apps are deployed on the server in many instances using docker-compose (replica number instances what we want).

The problem is that my app use Flyway, and when Docker starts my two services, they are almost identical in terms of starting up speed so they both try to apply the same migration script to the database, and the faster succeeds and the other one fails (because it tries to insert the same row as the other one in table schema_version).

What is the optimal solution for this type of problem?

The error logs :

app_webapp.2.5kv8hnbu5myt@sophea-linux    |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
app_webapp.2.5kv8hnbu5myt@sophea-linux    | Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed. Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 1519209964095
app_webapp.2.5kv8hnbu5myt@sophea-linux    | -> Applied to database : 90265964
app_webapp.2.5kv8hnbu5myt@sophea-linux    | -> Resolved locally    : 522480574
app_webapp.2.5kv8hnbu5myt@sophea-linux    |     at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:11

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a migration having been modified after having been applied. One reason for this can be if the DB was migrated from a Windows host and the line endings were changed as part of a Git commit with auto CRLF. This specific cause has been worked around in newer versions of Flyway.

Comment: I do not think it relates to this. I am using Linux OS and the sql syntax is perfectly valid.